# pandas:construct dataframe with > 1 ndim Categorical

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe with a multi index from flat data.  If three lists `a`, `b`, and `c`, that represent data, dates, and names, respectively.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

a = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.1282051282051282, 0.0],[0.0, 0.05128205128205128, 0.0]]
b = [datetime.datetime(1981, 10, 1, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1981, 10, 2, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1981, 10, 3, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1981, 10, 4, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1981, 10, 5, 0, 0),datetime.datetime(1981, 10, 6, 0, 0)]
c = [['Ririe Upstream', 'Grays Lake', 'Ririe'],['Ririe Upstream', 'Grays Lake', 'Ririe'],['Ririe Upstream', 'Grays Lake', 'Ririe'],['Ririe Upstream', 'Grays Lake', 'Ririe'],['Ririe Upstream', 'Grays Lake', 'Ririe'],['Ririe Upstream', 'Grays Lake', 'Ririe']]
```

I have found that I can use successfully create a dataframe with the desried format using the index for a single date and list of names with:

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[b[1]], c[1]], names=['date','name'])
tmp = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, data=a[1],columns=['data'])
```

Which returns:

```
                           data
date       name                
1981-10-02 Ririe Upstream   0.0
           Grays Lake       0.0
           Ririe            0.0
```

How can I construct a dataframe in this format using all of the data in `a`, `b` and `c`?

If I try:

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[b], c], names=['date','name'])
```

I get the error:

```
NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way.

First you need to ravel your data and make them all the same length.

```
a_new = np.ravel(a)
b_new = np.ravel(np.repeat(b, 3))
c_new = np.ravel(c)
```

Now we have 3 lists with equal length. Next we create the multi-index from b_new and c_new.

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(b_new, c_new), names = ('date', 'name'))
```

Finally we create our dataframe to get exactly what your looking for.

```
pd.DataFrame(a_new, index = idx, columns = ['data'])
```

---

Your issue with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` is that c has lists within lists. If you want to use that function you can do:

```
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([b,c[1]], names = ('date','name'))
```

Notice how we only want to use 1 list in c, it iterates for us.

Then:

```
pd.DataFrame(a_new, index = idx2, columns = ['data'])
```

Which will also get you your answer.(Note: You still need to use **a_new**)

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your are looking for a solution that runs in O(1) time, but the below can give you results in O(n) (n is the number of elements in list a or b or c):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(b)): #can be len(a) or len(c)
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[b[i]], c[i]], names=['date', 'name'])
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, data=a[i], columns=['data'])
    df = df.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Lets see what other people might suggest, but this might be the only way.